# Electron Desktop Application using GCP Speech To Text - Can not keep the connection open

Tags: node.js, electron, google-speech-api

I am trying to make a speech to text desktop app using GCP and Electron. I have it set up that when you click the record button it starts recording and shows in the speech to text in the box. My problem is that when you speak it transcribes at a pause and sends the data to the front end and then errors(`Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`) if you keep speaking. I have been advised that using a websocket to keep the connection open and continually sending the data will fix this. However I am unfamiliar with websockets and all of the tech I am using so my question is what sort of websocket would I use? Will this work using `ipcMain` or do I need a different websocket? And would anyone be able to advise how I would implement this? My code from my `index.js` file is below:

```
router.get("/speechToText", function (req, res, next) {
    speech.speechToTextFunction(recorder).on("data",data =>{
        console.log(data.results[0].alternatives[0].transcript);
        res.render('index', {answerInput: data.results[0].alternatives[0].transcript});
    });
```

which connects to my index.ejs file with the button:

```
<form action="/speechToText" method="GET" id="captureSpeech">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="capSpeech" onclick="">Capture Speech</button>
      </form>
```

and my speech.js file has this:

```
const speech = require("@google-cloud/speech");
const client = new speech.SpeechClient();

const encoding = "LINEAR16";
const sampleRateHertz = 16000;
const languageCode = "en-US";

const request = {
    config: {
        encoding: encoding,
        sampleRateHertz: sampleRateHertz,
        languageCode: languageCode,
    },
    interimResults: false, // If you want interim results, set this to true
    // singleUtterance: true
};

// Create a recognize stream
const recognizeStream = client
    .streamingRecognize(request)
    .on("error", console.error);

module.exports = {
    speechToTextFunction: (recorder) => {
        return recorder
            .record({
                sampleRateHertz: sampleRateHertz,
                threshold: 0,
                // Other options, see https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-record-lpcm16#options
                verbose: false,
                recordProgram: "sox", // Try also "arecord" or "sox"
                silence: "10.0",
            })
            .stream()
            .on("error", console.error)
            .pipe(recognizeStream)
    },
};
console.log("Listening, press Ctrl+C to stop.");
```

Any help and advice would be greatly appreciated